# Basic Flex Layout - Footer/Content?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to get a basic layout with content and a footer with flex.

I need the content to fill whatever is left over and the footer to be 60px tall. What is the best way to go about this?

```
<div class="container"> // 100% height
  <div class="one"></div> // Fill rest of height
  <div class="two"></div> // 60px tall
</div>
```

Here is a base jdfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vkd4v6Lt/1/

Answer (score 2):

Let me thank you for providing a base JSFiddle!
I [modified it](http://jsfiddle.net/q92o5wj4/) to do exactly what you want.

## Breakdown

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

First we remove margin and padding from the body because to allow `.container` to fill the complete viewport.

```
.container {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Make `.container` at least as big as the viewport is to fill it completely.

```
.one {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Fill the remaining space in the flexbox with this element, as `.two` has a set height of `60px`.

As pointed out by Bram Vanroy you can use `calc` (and also other methods) if the footer has a set height. However this also works if you don't explicitly set the footer height and let the footer take all the height it needs and then stretch the content container to accommodate that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to flex. Do it with `calc`.

```
.container {
    height: 100%;
}

.one {
    height: calc(100% - 60px);
}

.two {
    height: 60px;
    background: blue;
}
```

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/vkd4v6Lt/3/).

As Cu3PO42 mentions in the comments, min-height might be the better option for your needs.

Comment: I advise you set `min-height: calc(100% - 60px)` for `.one` as the content may otherwise overflow it.

Comment: @Cu3PO42 Good point, though I think OP should figure out for himself if he wants to use min-height or overflow: auto. It seems that the whole point is to fit everything inside a non-scrollable window, in which case `overflow: auto` on `.one` might be the better option. (However, if that's the case I'd advise making .two position fixed so that the overflow is on the window and not on .one.

Comment: To me this looks just like a standard footer fix. Make sure the footer is at the bottom even if the content doesn't push it that far.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;           /* As tall as the containig block */
  display: flex;          /* Magic begins */
  flex-direction: column; /* Column layout */
}
.one { flex: 1; }         /* Grow to fill available space */
.two { height: 60px; }    /* 60px tall */
```

However, there is a problem: in order to make `height: 100%` work, the containing block needs an explicit height (otherwise, it would be a circular definition):

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   generated box's [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#containing-block). If the height of the containing
>   block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
>   height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value
>   computes to 'auto'.

So you also need

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.one {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
}
.two {
  height: 60px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Primm Safari needs a `-webkit-` prefix for the flex properties: `display: -webkit-flex`, `-webkit-flex-direction: column`, `-webkit-flex: 1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to care about `calc()`, `vh` or lots of `height: 100%`, you can use fixed positioning:

```css
.one, .two {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.one {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 60px;
  background: red;
}
.two {
  height: 60px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```

And it has the advantage it works on very old browsers.